# Sound Blaster Z DDL/DTS setting not working

Tags: audio, encoding, creative

I've just bought and installed a Sound Blaster Z card and when i try to select DDL or DTS it says: "The task requires exclusive use of your audio device. please stop playback and try again." but there is nothing playing on my PC.

I've tried re-installing drivers and software, I tried exclusive mode on and off, I tried the setting to allow access to the microphone, I tried the new driverupdate 6.0.102.74 for Sound Blaster Z, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thanks.

(Win10 1909, Creative driver: SBZ_CD_L13_1_01_11)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, you have to go to windows settings then privacy and security then microphone and turn on microphone access you can have the option below that says "let apps access your microphone" off but the top option microphone access has to be on

Answer (score 0):

Even if an app is not playing audio, it can claim the audio driver.

If exclusive audio mode is enabled, other hardware will give a similar error.

I'm not sure if exclusive audio mode needs to be enabled for DDL or DTS, but you can try playing with that setting.

My settings are in dutch, so I have to guess what they are in English and where you find them. So please keep this in mind when you look for the setting. It might be slightly differently named.

Right-click the speaker in the bottom right, near your clock and select Open Soundsettings (top one)

You see 2 sections, Output and Input. Below Output, the first link is device properties. Click it.

On this page, if the settings window is wide enough, you will find at the top right: extra device properties. If its not wide enough, you need to scroll down for this link.

This opens a control panel app.

In the Advanced tab, you will find the 2nd panel to be Exclusive mode. Try toggling the second checkbox and see if that alters the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already tried that end it made no difference. From what I've read exclusive mode is better turned off for this. Also I've had suggestions that the option to allow apps access to microphone needs to be turned on. But that also didn't work.

Comment: Try turning on exclusive mode, reboot pc and then see if it works.

Comment: Also, please edit your post and provide ALL steps you already tried to rule things out and get answers you don't need.

Comment: That also has no effect, I keep getting the same message.